# I need to sync the second library but the IDE tells me that he can not find it why and what is the problem

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

//this is the full gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        version_kotlin = "1.3.11"
        version_core = "1.0.1"
        version_constraint_layout = "1.1.3"
        version_lifecycle_extensions = "2.0.0"
        version_material = "1.0.0"
        version_navigation = "2.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

// there is a warning message that appears here that says (this inspection reports that different IDE and Gradle plugin versions are used. This can cause inconsistencies between IDE and Gradle builds in error reporting or code behaviour)

```
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"

        classpath  "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
```

Comment: can you share the gradle file code?

Comment: I added it to it can you please check it